# Get text of SWT Text component before modification

Tags: java, swt, listener

I have a SWT `Text` component with a Modify listener and when I write something on the Text, the listener code is executed, inside the listener I'm getting and printing the new text, so for example, if the original text was `"initial text"` and when I type something, let's say `"initial text2"`, the listener will print `"initial text2"`, which is fine, but I also need the original text before the text was modified.

Is there a way to do this? I don't want to use `keyPressed` listener because it will not handle when the user pastes the text using the mouse.

So far my code looks like this:

```
Text myText = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
myText.setText("initial text");

myText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
        //Get here the original text
        String content = myText.getText(); //This line return the modified string
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listen for `SWT.Verify` instead of `SWT.Modify`:

```
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
text.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        // Get the source widget
        Text source = (Text) e.widget;

        // Get the text
        final String oldS = source.getText();
        final String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);

        System.out.println(oldS + " -> " + newS);
    }
});
```

This will print the text before and after the modification.